# Overlay view like YouTube app

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube, android-widget, overlay

I am creating an app which does some tracking on a map. The tracking part works great inside my activity.

However, I want to have some kind of small overlay in the bottom right corner (like the minimalised video playback in the YouTube app) that stays there, even when I switch activities.

I have looked at [this](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/), but it's not really what I need. I don't need it to be moveable, and I think this is impossible to keep when switching activities.

Is there some kind of class that I can implement (Widget, Fragment, ...) that would fit my needs?

Thank you,
DebboR

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late and probably not relevant to you anymore, but maybe somebody else will find this helpful.

I don't think it's possible to switch activities and keep a certain view on screen. How I think this should be done is have a main activity with fragments that swap and in the activity's layout have a view overlay on top of the fragments container.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Container for the fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    <!-- This view will overlay the fragment in the bottom right corner -->
    <View
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```